# classpath for maven-embedded-glassfish-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, glassfish

I am using maven embedded-glassfish plugin and trying to use external database with it.

Now I need to provide specific JDBC driver on classpath, just like mentioned here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26576_01/doc.312/e24932/embedded-server-guide.htm

But I could not find out **how** to setup classpath (preferably inside pom.xml) for this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the appserv-rt.jar (located in Glassfish's lib directory) file to your project's build path (it will add all the dependancies, if you want to avoid this you should first create a library with the jar and then add the library)